# How to hide jqgrid thumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have jqgrid with lots of data..I want to hide thumb of jqgrid which is on mousewheel going up and down in scrollbar..data are dynamic so I am giving you basic example..Is there any way to hide thumb of jqgrid vertical scrollbar only?

```js
var data = [
  [48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"],
  [48769, "APPR", "", "77733337", "ENTERED"],
  [48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"],
  [48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"],
  [48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"],
  [48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"],
  [48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"],
  [48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"],
  [48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"],
  [48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"],
  [48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"],
  [48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"],
  [48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"],
  [48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"],
  [48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"],
];

$("#grid").jqGrid({
  datatype: "local",
  height: 250,
  colNames: ['Inv No', 'Thingy', 'Blank', 'Number', 'Status'],
  colModel: [{
    name: 'id',
    index: 'id',
    width: 60,
    sorttype: "int"
  }, {
    name: 'thingy',
    index: 'thingy',
    width: 90,
    sorttype: "date"
  }, {
    name: 'blank',
    index: 'blank',
    width: 30
  }, {
    name: 'number',
    index: 'number',
    width: 80,
    sorttype: "float"
  }, {
    name: 'status',
    index: 'status',
    width: 80,
    sorttype: "float"
  }],
  caption: "Stack Overflow Example",
  // ondblClickRow: function(rowid,iRow,iCol,e){alert('double clicked');}
});

var names = ["id", "thingy", "blank", "number", "status"];
var mydata = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  mydata[i] = {};
  for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
    mydata[i][names[j]] = data[i][j];
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++) {
  $("#grid").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<link href="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="grid"></table>
```

[image: THUMBSCROLL IMAGE]

**UPDATE**
I am using 4.6.0 version of jqgrid..This is just example ignore keys and how it enter data in grid..Basic question is to hide thumb of scrollbar

**UPDATE1**
datatype:json ,rownum=50 ,height:350 and paging is there as scroll:true

Comment: which "thumb" you want to hide? Sorry, but it's absolutely unclear what you need to implement. You should always write **which version of jqGrid and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) you use jqGrid**. Moreover you should include more realistic JavaScript code, close to what you use. The JavaScript, which you posted, is the example of the worst way how jqGrid can be used: the input data contains id duplicates, the data will be filled by `addRowData`, wrong `sorttype`..

Comment: please see updated question @Oleg

Comment: What you mean with "thumb of scrollbar"?

Comment: sorry for unclear question..I have updated my question..@Oleg

Comment: I try to explain you that you should **more clear, more detailed to describe what you do and what you want to implement**. For example switch of the monitor to solve your problem. Is it OK? It could be **many interpretations of the problem, many reasons and many solution**. Which `datatype` you use? Do you use paging of data or not? The solution could be from the usage of `height: "auto", rowNum: 10000` or `height: "auto", rowNum: 10`, but with the pager, or the usage of `perfectScrollbar` like https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/k0j2umco/3/. **You should describe clear what you do and what you need**

Comment: Sorry for late reply..I updated my question..but I do not think there is need of that because I just want to hide thumb..as when user scroll down request continuously going and it took time so I want to hide so that just up and down button will be display to scroll down..@Oleg

Answer (score 0):

If the height is not big enough to display all the rows, then it has to create a scroll bar.
If you want to remove the scroll bar, either increase the height or decrease the rownum.